# ORA-12154 error after Oracle 11g R1 installation

Tags: oracle11g

I faced this error while trying to connect to the oracle database using Sql plus tool
And I am using the built in user "SCOTT"

I've installed oracle 11g r1 on Windows 7 (64bit)

this is my first time in Oracle world, So please help in an easy steps

Comment: what is your service name ? can you show us the tnsnames.ora file ?

Comment: can you ping server with tnsping

Comment: I found the file under "E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Install\product\11.1.0\db_2\NETWORK\ADMIN" and I found My server Name wrong "MTAHA-PC" and I correct it to be "MTAHAPC" but the error still comming

Comment: I tried tnsping "tnsping MTAHAPC"                                   And I got this error .. TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: post the the `tnsnames.ora` & `listener.ora` files.

Comment: I tried to reinstall it again because I remember that there is an warning during the installation & this is the message 

"Checking Network Configuration requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
Problem: The install has detected that the primary IP address of the system is DHCP-assigned.   (to be continue...)

Comment: Recommendation: Oracle supports installations on systems with DHCP-assigned IP addresses; However, before you can do this, you must configure the Microsoft LoopBack Adapter to be the primary network adapter on the system.  See the Installation Guide for more details on installing the software on systems configured with DHCP" 

And I did the LoopBack Adapter but I still have this warning
Is this warning have a relation with my first Issue I posted here?

Comment: this is the tnsnames.ora

# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

MTAHAPC =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MTahaPC.lan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MTAHAPC)
    )
  )

Comment: this is the Letener.ora

# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MTahaPC.lan)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

Comment: I tried to ping using tnsping MTAHAPC.lan and I got this error

C:\>tnsping MTAHAPC.lan

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on 20-FEB-2
012 12:44:53

Used parameter files:
E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTO
COL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.68)(PORT=1521)))
OK (0 msec)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you startup the oracle instance service and listener.

Go to 
Services > OracleService and start it.
Services > OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener and start it

Answer (score 0):

If this is a local test database on a developer PC (eg. not a server with static IP) and you don't have to access it over the network I would suggest binding the listener only to localhost. Find you listener.ora file and change what probably is your computername now to localhost:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )
  )
```

After this restart your listener. (look for something called OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener in your services panel)

You can try to connect using ezconnect now (replace username, password and servicename by the actual values):

```
sqlplus username/password@//localhost:1521/servicename
```

If you don't know your service name look at the services panel and locate a service called OracleServiceXYZ where XYZ is your servicename.

If this work you can also change your hostname to localhost in tnsnames.ora and use the shorter:

```
sqlplus username/password@tnsname
```

to connect.